# Using Iframes on different subdomains

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Hello a bit new to this.

I am using an iframe which needs to be presented on a page on one our sites, the issue I am having is I need this

each site is the same, barring branding, other than the subdomain e.g site1.cloud.co.uk, site2.cloud.co.uk, site3.cloud.co.uk etc.

I have several of these and they all need the iframe displayed on the same page. I was defining these in one document and listing them one by one as below:

```
<iframe id="paylive_frame" src="https://site1.cloud.co.uk/Payments/purchased.php" width="103%" height="1250px"> </iframe>

<iframe id="paylive_frame2" src="https://site2.cloud.co.uk/Payments/purchased.php" width="103%" height="1250px"> </iframe>
```

Doing this displays the iframes but in each page they are displayed slightly lower down. I have tried to resolve this using some CSS which then allows them to display in the correct position on the page however in the example about the fields on subdomain site1 become unresponsive and will only be funtional on site2. Tried using 'document.domain' method after looking into this but same issue.

Hopefully this makes sense

Quite new to this as I say and not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I can't quite figure out what you mean here. Could you flesh out your question and maybe show some more code?

Comment: Sure wasn't too sure how well I had explained myself. I have 10 subdomains (all hosted on same server) each with a site on them and on each I have a payment page on which I need to present the same payment form within an iframe. As in the code above i have thus far listed each iframe one for each site however this has the effect of on site1 the form is at the top of the page on site2 the form starts lower down on the page etc. I fixed this using CSS but when I do the form becomes unresponsive. I feel it cant be that complicated a solution but cant for the life of me cant figure out the reason

Comment: I think you need to post the CSS you used to fix it. It's possible that that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: #container
{
 width:2200px;
 height:1250px;
 margin:auto;
}

#outerdiv
{
 width:1306px;
 height:1500px;
 position:relative;
}

#innerdiv
{
 position:absolute;
 top:-1200px;
 left:0px;
 width:600px;
 height:1250px
}
The above is the CSS I used in the end to position the Iframes

Comment: When I position it using the CSS however the text fields on the iframe lose focus so no details can be entered on the form